# How to add scales= "free_y" to facet by using toggle switch in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, facet

I have created a `facet_geo` plot and would like to provide an option to the user to **enable/disable free y-axis scale** for comparison.

I have previously done this using below method but that requires putting whole code twice:

**server.R**

```
enable_free_y <- input$id_switch_tab1_free_y_scale

if(!enable_free_y){
plot1
}
else{
plot2
}
```

Is there a way that I can add this `if condition` to `facet_geo` within the **plot code** itself rather than having two different plots for toggle.

to add `scales = "free_y"` within plot code I have tried:

```
enable_free_y <- input$id_switch_tab1_free_y_scale

facet_geo(~ State.UnionTerritory, grid = "in_state_ut_grid2", 
                      label = "code", 
                      
                      if (enable_free_y){"scales = 'free_y', "} else{""}
                      
                      move_axes = T)
```

and also tried:

```
enable_free_y <- input$id_switch_tab1_free_y_scale

facet_geo(~ State.UnionTerritory, grid = "in_state_ut_grid2", 
                      label = "code", 
                      
                      if (enable_free_y){scales = 'free_y', } else{""}
                      
                      move_axes = T)
```

But None of the above options work.

**UPDATE:**

Updating Results after getting the Answer:
https://vineet-sansi.shinyapps.io/IndiaCovid19Dashboard/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wrap the whole `facet_geo` in your `if-else`, not just the `scales` parameter.

Comment: yes this worked, thanks @Limey !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
facet_geo(~ State.UnionTerritory, grid = "in_state_ut_grid2", 
          label = "code", 
          scales = if(enable_free_y) 'free_y' else 'fixed',
          move_axes = T)
```

Comment: Thanks again @Ronak Shah. This is exactly what I was trying to code but wasn't able to. Really appreciate your continuous help over the time !!